# Monitor download files in sharepoint 2010 foundation

Tags: auditing

I need to monitor the download files, I have this tool https://auditlogsp.codeplex.com/ but it does not have the option to monitor downloads, only when I view the properties of a document

Answer (score 0):

Well if all your documents are within the site scope.

A simple and easy approach is to use any IIS log analysis tools for the required day and see the downloaded files ..

You can find many freeware tools for this case.

Hope this helps !!